# Running queries in Parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, sqldatareader

I need to optimize my Data Access through ADO.Net. For requeriments of the project I can´t use Linq or Entity...

So I´m launching 15 independents ADO.NET queries. I´m following the standards, Open the connection, launching the query, use the DataReader for getting the Data, storing them in classes, and finally I close the connection...

But I´m feeling like the project is not fast enough. So, Guys, Can you all teach me some tips for improve the speed of it?

My Database is SQL Server, and as far as I can, I´m lauching queries by entity.

EDITED:

```
private void Connect(string comando) {
    try { 
        string cadena = "connection_data";
        Cn = new SqlConnection(cadena);
        Cn.Open();
        SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand(comando, Cn);
        Datos = Com.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // 
    }
}

    private void Close()
    {
        try 
        { 
            Cn.Close();
            Datos.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // 
        }
    }

    public List<class1> getClass1(double id)
    {
        Connect("SELECT TOP (5) CASE WHEN [table1].[attribute1] IN (7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 28, 29) THEN 'random_name' " +
            "WHEN [table1].[attribute3] = NULL AND [table1].[attribute2] = NULL THEN 'random_name2' WHEN [table1].[attribute3] = NULL THEN [table1].[attribute3] ELSE " 
// bla bla bla bla and so on and I have 15 massive queries like this one;

        List<class1> res = new List<class1>();

        if (Datos.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (Datos.Read())
            {
                class1obj = new class1();
                obj.at1= class1.cont + 1;
                obj.at2= class1.cont + 1;
                class1.cont++;
                obj.at3= "random_value";
                obj.at4= Datos.GetValue(0);
                obj.at5= Datos.GetValue(1);
                res.Add(obj);
            }
            Close();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: You should show the code and the queries...

Comment: @Gilad Green. Why? Standard queries with standard code... The queries are optimized and the code is the standard one... Anyway, just for If I´m missing something, I edit it...

Comment: Ya I can understand that but I'm saying about code and queries because maybe one can join queries or maybe you can do stuff in parallel. In any case for determining that and not give irrelevant answers some code is useful

Comment: The queries are completely joined. They are coming from another team... But, "parallel something" sounds interesting. Can you tell me more? You mean Using different connection?

Comment: I'd love to elaborate but would prefer to first see a bit what am I talking about before just throwing "do that and that" :)

Comment: Done @Gilad Green. Those queries are massive and I have to change the real names of attributes, values, tables,... and I have 15... I can´t show you each one... I´m gonna try using a few connection in the meantime (How can I launch them in parallel)... ;) Thanks Mate :)

Comment: does each query "map" to a different class you need to create?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118298/discussion-between-eliasmp-and-gilad-green).

Comment: **Optimization Tip:** replace the `SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand(comando, Cn);` line with `Cn.Open();` in your `Connect` method because a database connection should be opened as late as possible and should be closed as soon as possible.

Comment: @user1451111 Really appreciate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have a function of creating for each class then what you can do is something like this:

Instead of having a function `getClass1` Have an interface:

```
public interface IBuildClass<TClass>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TClass>> BuildAsync(double id);
}
```

Add a base class for the interface that will request as a dependency a connection object to the database

```
public abstract class BuildClassBase<TClass> : IBuildClass<TClass>
{
    public BuildClassBase(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TClass>> BuildAsync(double id)
    {
        //Execute query and pass results to InnerBuid
        return InnerBuildAsync(/*Pass DataTable*/);
    }

    public abstract async Task<IEnumerable<TClass>> InnerBuildAsync(DataTable data);

    //Ctor of each derived class will set the value
    public string Query { get; protected set; }
    public SqlConnection Connection {get; set; }
}
```

And then a specific implementation matching each class you want to create. You can also add a factory for them:

```
public interface IBuildClassFactory
{
    IBuildClass<TClass> GetBuilder<TClass>();
}
```

Then in your code where you currently execute all 15 methods you can create a `Task` for each class and then `await buildClassFactory.GetBuilder<ClassA>().BuildAsync(id)`. Something like:

```
double id = 1;
Task createClassA = buildClassFactory.GetBuilder<ClassA>().BuildAsync(id);
Task createClassB = buildClassFactory.GetBuilder<ClassB>().BuildAsync(id);
Task createClassC = buildClassFactory.GetBuilder<ClassC>().BuildAsync(id);
....

Task.WaitAll(createClassA, createClassB, createClassC....);

//And then get result from tasks
```

Comment: Uuuuffff. Thanks @Gilad Green. It looks could be work. At least it improve my time of response. But this surpasses me. I´ll need time for implement it. I´ll let you know about it... Thanks mate for yor efford... You´re cool :))))

Comment: @EliasMP - with much pleasure :) look deep into dependency injection - really makes an improvement to the code  :) Read about it and maybe also previous questions in SO about it. check about IoC containers like Castle Windsor/ ninject......